# OpenCart Mult-store setup over different domains?

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

Is it possible to setup Open Cart as a multi-store installation over different domain names?

I have a OC setup on domain www.xxx.xx. The official documentation explains how to setup OC on a subdomain (i.e. subdomain.xxx.xx). That is OK and we can do that. However we need ot have the stores running on completely different domains. That means i.e. the multi-store clone installed on subdomain.xxx.xx accessible through www.somedomain.xx.

Now I am aware that I could redirect the TLD somedomain.xx into the subdomain installation. However that is not really what we need. We need for it to act as completely different stores.

Question is how do I do this? And is this even possible?
(as I can imagine that there might be some problems with sessions and cookies set in such an environment? besides possible other issues...)

(we have our own servers with access to root so our options are not limited with hosting accounts)

Comment: Take a look at this guide: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=27538 Matty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You really need to have the multi-domain multi-store, You can achieve it by setting up the sub-domain multi-store first and then making the domains to be aliases to this sub-domains, e.g.

- Default Store -> http://www.domain.com
- Store 1 -> http://sub1.domain.com
- Store 2 -> http://sub2.domain.com
- Store 3 -> http://sub3.domain.com

and then

- http://www.domain1.com -> http://sub1.domain.com
- http://www.domain2.com -> http://sub2.domain.com
- http://www.domain3.com -> http://sub3.domain.com

Though the Store 1 could be accessed now by both http://sub1.domain.com and http://www.domain1.com it is up to marketing to deliver only http://www.domain1.com URL. Perhaps some other `.htaccess` restrictions/redirect from direct access to http://sub1.domain.com may be set but this is not necessary at all. Using these aliases to sub-domains You should be able to preserve all the functionality of multi-store on sub-domains...

Comment: Hi.. could you go into detail on how to achieve this condifuration?

Comment: @shadyyx I have not working on second store as well. please help me

Comment: Hi, this answer was posted in 12/2013, probably for OC 1.2.9 or similarly old :-) I am not sure how OC and it's multistore works nowadays. But I believe after setting everything up the solution described above still applies as that is general networking which hasn't changed since ages. A direct help with setting a multistore in OC can be found online, there are plenty of guides on that matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to setup opencart multi stores with different domains like domain1.com, domain2.com etc.

If we setup multi-stores as subdomains, then:

1. By default the same cart will be shared for all stores.
2. Customer won't be asked to login if he goes to another store.
   etc.

However for you the above cases will not happen as you're using different domains. Since you need the stores to be independent, it'll be better to assign separate customer groups for each store - so that the customer will be asked to sign up for each store.

Eventhough the stores are independent all stores share the same admin section, that is even if we login using `domain2.com/admin` - it will get redirected to `domain1.com/admin` after login.