# Opencart Multi-store 1.5.6 shared session

Tags: session, opencart, shared, cart

I've got a opencart multi-store, though the shared session doesn't work for me.
When i put a item in my cart from store1.com it will not appear on store2.com...

My multistore looks like this, so with different domains. 
store1.com 
store2.com

In my main store1.com header its got differtent iframe's:

```
<iframe src="http://www.store1.com/catalog/view/javascript/crossdomain.php?session_id=95e5c425bc5df1ecff3406eb0f587018" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.store2.com/catalog/view/javascript/crossdomain.php?session_id=95e5c425bc5df1ecff3406eb0f587018" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

I see in my header of store2 that its got 2 the same iframe's:

```
<iframe src="http://www.store2.com/catalog/view/javascript/crossdomain.php?session_id=95e5c425bc5df1ecff3406eb0f587018" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.store2.com/catalog/view/javascript/crossdomain.php?session_id=95e5c425bc5df1ecff3406eb0f587018" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Does anybody knows what the problem could be?

Thank you very much!

Kind regards,

Bram

@shadyyx yes the store2.com is pointed to the main store1.com. though i copied the templates and used one for the store1.com and the other one for store2.com.

store1.com: goo.gl/4ZekFU
store2.com: goo.gl/SWaZ1R

Comment: Are those domains (or at least one of them) actually an alias to a subdomain that is registered as a part of multistore setup? I do not understand what are those iframes good/needed for - but if You are trying to share the session between different (2nd level) domains it won't work...

Comment: @JayGilford I am sure Daniel has it in his mind - at least after some 1.5.9X release :-)

Comment: @shadyyx: Actually, the next release will be 2.0

Comment: @shadyyx or Jay Gilford thank you for the answere's its just a normal multistore install. Though it does not seems to work, is there or are there simple solutions for this? I thought there something in these iframes that causes it to not work...

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314105/opencart-mult-store-setup-over-different-domains and check my answer - is Your setup the same as I suggested there (domains are aliases to subdomains under the main store domain)?